# Prove that if $a,b,c>0$ then ${1\over a}+{1\over b}+{1\over c}\ge{2\over a+b}+{2\over b+c}+{2\over c+a}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Prove that if $a,b,c>0$ then ${1\over a}+{1\over b}+{1\over c}\ge{2\over a+b}+{2\over b+c}+{2\over c+a}$

Excuse me but I am new to inequalities and have been practicing some questions including the one above. The one above looks easy but for me is not. I tried to use AM-GM-HM but led to even greater problems. Here is my attempt:
$${a+b+c\over3}\ge{3\over{1\over a}+{1\over b}+{1\over c}}$$
$${1\over 2}\biggl({(a+b)+(b+c)+(c+a)\over3}\biggr)\ge{3\over{1\over a}+{1\over b}+{1\over c}}$$
$$\iff {{1\over a}+{1\over b}+{1\over c}\over3}\ge\Biggl({1\over{6\over a+b}+{6\over b+c}+{6\over c+a}}\Biggr)$$
I could barely spot the wanted up there but cannot continue further.
I also got that
$${2\over a+b}+{2\over b+c}+{2\over c+a}\ge{1\over a+b+c}$$
Any help, if maybe a different method, would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if you plug a=b=c=2? The first and second both inequalities would be invalid. I think it is for $a,b,c \le 1$

Comment: @LoveInvariants yes I made a mistake, its meant to be 6 instead of 3.

Comment: I'm talking about the question though. I think it is wrong.

Comment: Oh it's written wrong than you.

Comment: It is fixed now

Comment: Take 2 at a time eg ${1\over a}+{1\over b}$ and then other two ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We apply the arithmetic-harmonic mean inequality in variables $a,b$:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)\ge \frac{2}{1/(1/a)+1/(1/b)}=\frac{2}{a+b}$$

Now do this twice more: in variables $a,c$, and in variables $b,c$.  Then add the three inequalities.